# How to merge columns while preserving result values?

Tags: sql, mariadb

How to merge columns while preserving result values?

```
        select user_poi_no, tm.id, modelName, item, projectName
        from tb_user_poi p
                 inner join tb_member tm on p.id_pk = tm.id_pk
                 inner join tb_poi tp on p.poiNo = tp.poiNo
                 inner join tb_model t on tp.modelNo = t.modelNo
        where tm.id_pk = 1;
```

The result of the above sql is:

```
user_poi_no, id, modelname, item, projectname
1, q, drawing 3, 1, basic project
7, q, drawing 3, 2, project name test
8, q, drawing 3, 2, project name test
9, q, drawing 3, 2, project name test
```

But what I want is the result below.

```
user_poi_no, id, modelname, item, projectname
1, q, drawing 3, 1, basic project
7 8 9, q, drawing 3, 2, project name test
```

I tried to solve the problem using distinct or group by, but I ran into a problem that the 4 columns `user_poi_no, id, modelname, item, projectname` are not maintained.

How can I get the results I want?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` for that

```
select group_concat(user_poi_no order by user_poi_no), 
       tm.id, 
       modelName, 
       group_concat(item order by item), 
       projectName
from tb_user_poi p
inner join tb_member tm on p.id_pk = tm.id_pk
inner join tb_poi tp on p.poiNo = tp.poiNo
inner join tb_model t on tp.modelNo = t.modelNo
where tm.id_pk = 1
group by tm.id, modelName, projectName
```